# MX does not work, after setup CNAME

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record, cname-record

I have the following configuration in the DNS server (1-configuration):

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Host name   |  IP address/URL        | Record Type  | MX Pref | TTL
--------------------------------------------------------------------
@           | awf.rhcloud.com.       | CNAME(Alias) |   n/a   | 1800
www         | http://example.com     | URL Redirect |   n/a   | 1800
mail        | domain.mail.yandex.net.| CNAME(Alias) |   n/a   | 1800
```

and MX part is

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
HOST NAME   |  MAILSERVER HOST NAME  | MAIL TYPE  | MX Pref | TTL
--------------------------------------------------------------------
@           | mx.yandex.ru.          | MX         | 10      | 1800
```

in the above case MX record actuality does not working if I change `@` and `www` as below MX starts working (2-configuration):

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Host name   |  IP address/URL        | Record Type  | MX Pref | TTL
--------------------------------------------------------------------
@           | http://www.example.com | URL Redirect |   n/a   | 1800
www         | awf.rhcloud.com.       | CNAME(Alias) |   n/a   | 1800
```

How can I make such that MX starts to work for the first configuration(without `www`). Is it possible, is there any tricks to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you reference a CNAME record in an MX record?](http://serverfault.com/questions/81402/can-you-reference-a-cname-record-in-an-mx-record)

Comment: Here it is not an issue of having an MX record referencing a CNAME, but instead having a CNAME in combination with other records types, such as in http://serverfault.com/questions/481243/cname-domain-to-another-domain-but-keep-different-spf-records-for-the-two

Comment: @b0fh It's worse than that. Some of the record types are not even real types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `CNAME` record indicates that the name is an alias for another, for all record types. You are not allowed to have other record types for the same name when a `CNAME` is present.

Remove the `CNAME` for `@` and replace it with explicit records (`A`, `AAAA`, `SRV`, etc) for all the types you need.